# Is it bad to convert c# datetime properties in the get and set to and from utc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In our Entity Framework app we are storing datetimes as UTC.  The client uses a reflection utility to convert object graphs to their users timezone, and then back to utc when submitting changes to the server.

The utility works fine, but i'm considering a cleaner approach where I add a unmapped TimeZoneInfo property on the base class with a default value set to UTC, and then for each datetime property i would modify it like so:

```
    private DateTime _endTime;
    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _endTime.ConvertFromUtc(TimeZone);
        }
        set
        {
            _endTime = value.ConvertToUtc(TimeZone);
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the backing field is always stored as a UTC value.  If the TimeZone proeprty is set to UTC, then the ConvertTo/From extension methods will not do any conversion and will simply return the backing fields value.  Whereas, if the TimeZone is set to anything else then the conversion will take place, leaving the backing field in UTC.

What i'm wondering is if there are issues i'm not thinking of.  For instance, I'm assuming it would serialize with a value based on the current TimeZone property...is that true?  Also, would this work for code first entities in EF?  My hope is that if the TimeZone is changed it would *not* trigger a change in the dbcontext. Are there any other considerations that i'm missing that would make this a bad idea, and what would a DDD implementator think?

**Edit**
To clarify the use case a little more, the service layer will retrieve the values from the db, serialize, and send it to the MVC Controller.  The service layer does not know of the users timezone. In my mvc app the web controller cached the user timezone at logon.  This controller will then use that value to set the TimeZone property on the object.  It will then submit it to the client via JSON.  The TimeZone property on the base class represents the current timzone of the object, not the users timezone. The values are always stored as UTC and the controller which sends the data to the client is responsible to make sure it is set to the correct timezone.

The biggest reason i am considering this is for business logic.  The object in question is a schedule which has a start and end time.  There are three requirements that would be easier to perform if the object were set to the users timezone.  For instance, schedules cannot span weeks, so if it starts on Saturday (end of week) and ends on Sunday (start of week) it must be split into two different schedules. For some reason i have a more difficult time when working with datetime logic, and so anything i can do to simplify it is a plus for maintenance.

Comment: Why not just expose them as UTC, and let the client perform a conversion if they want to?

Comment: I agree. This is a bad idea. There's times when you might actually need the UTC value, and more to the point, there's situations where you might not be able to reasonably set the `TimeZone` property to the correct value (dependency injection, modelbinders, etc.) Personally, I just add extension methods to `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset`, which it looks like the client has already done (the `ConvertFromUtc` and `ConvertToUtc` methods you use in your custom getter and setter above). That's usually sufficient to get the TZ specific value when you need it.

Comment: That limitation with schedules and weeks, are they based on the user's week or the server's week?

Comment: @c_manboy, can you check my question here and my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think my question was well worded, nor thought out.  I decided to implement the above idea into part of my project and found that it just creates more confusion than it's worth.  It's also adds too much risk, especially if used in objects that are persisted to the db, where a programmer may fail to convert the object back to utc.

Instead i am adding a much, much simpler way by adding an extension method to easily calculate based on a specified timezone.  The extension method assumes the datetime object is in UTC:

```
    public static DateTime? As(this DateTime? dt, TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone)
    {
        if (dt.HasValue)
            return dt.Value.As(targetTimeZone);
        else
            return dt;
    }
    public static DateTime As(this DateTime dt, TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, targetTimeZone);
    }
```

This ensures the underlying object is not mutated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your application's timezone will be the web server's timezone! If the user is visiting your site from another timezone, the conversion will be wrong.

You need to make your page determine via the browser what their timezone is and use that for conversions.

If you need the user's current time, you can use this:

```
Date.now()

// Or this if you need support for old browsers, like IE8
new Date().getTime()
```

That will give you UTC time in milliseconds since January 1st 1970. You will have to later convert that to C# time by doing this in your application:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(valueFromJS * 10000 + 621355860000000000);
```

If you don't need the current time but a date+time entered by the user in a date picker, then you should create a date object in the browser from that and send the `getTime()` of that object. This way your web server always receives UTC time and it's up to the browser do the appropriate conversion.

You can also use `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, which will return the amount of minutes UTC is ahead of the user timezone. So if the user is in GMT -4, that function will return 240. If for some reason you need that in the web server, you can send that value from the browser. Alternatively, if your application has users, you can even store that as a setting and simply use that.

Now, to display the date in the browser's timezone, you have to either know beforehand the user's timezone (from a previous request or a user setting) or just send it in UTC and then convert that via JavaScript in the browser.

There are also useful libraries to deal with timezone problems. For example:

http://momentjs.com/timezone/

http://tzdata-javascript.org

Comment: My question may not be well worded, but it is not really about javascript nor any other front end.  My question is really about creating server side properties that allow for toggling between timezones for server side computations.   (The decision was already made to send datetimes to the client in their timezone.  We may revisit this later, but for now it is established.)

Comment: Oh, and wasn't using `DateTimeOffset` the best option?

Comment: No, unfortunately datetimeoffset fails to store the actual timezone (which i find highly unfortunate).

Comment: Why? If you can instantiate it with `DateTimeOffset(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan offset)`, giving the user's time zone.